# How do I indent with multiple cursors to the same horizontal position in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, text-editing

I'm looking for an easy way to do this in VS Code. (I'm writing an interpreter so there's lots of boilerplate!)

[image: indents are different] [image: indents are different]

One strategy I found is to

add too much space

[image]

then ESC and multi-line down again,

[image]

then select word right

[image]

then select word left

[image]

and then backspace for

[image]

but I'm wondering if there is a shortcut or extension that does this in one step (instead of 2n + 5 steps).

Comment: related to https://superuser.com/questions/474284/in-sublime-text-2-how-can-i-indent-out-to-a-straight-column-with-multiple-curso?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

This extension will accomplish this:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=annsk.alignment

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this extension.

[image: demostration]

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=yo1dog.cursor-align